# Make a input text format automatically as a date with "/"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a "subscribe to my newsletter" form and I am using a clothing website as a reference  https://www.emibeachwear.com.br/ (You will find the form on the footer of the website)

On the footer there is this input called "data de aniversário" or "birthdate" if you translate it to English.
Using chrome inspect element I saw that it is a **Text** input. Even though it is a text it still formats as a date.

How do I do that? Should I use javascript? If so, how?

Here is what I have now:

```
<div class="newsletter" style="background:transparent; color:white;">
      <label class="email"> E-MAIL
          <input  class="caixa" type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="E-MAIL" style="border:0;"required />
      </label >
      <label class="aniversario"> DATA DE ANIVERSÁRIO
          <input class="caixa" type="date" placeholder="DATA DE ANIVERSÁRIO" style="border:0;" max-length="10" required />
      </label>
      <input class="cadastrar caixa" type="submit" value="CADASTRAR" style="border:0;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Very clever answer by @Spectric, but still I can't figure out why you wouldn't use `<input type="date" />`

Comment: I'm editing a Wordpress theme. And when I use Type="date" it loads a placeholder that I don't want to use. On top of that, I'm doing this for a client, she is really picky with the visual of her website. So, I want to do it the way she envisioned it. Since she wants a footer just like the one from the website, I came across this challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
  var s = input.value.replaceAll("/", "").match(/.{1,2}/g);
  if (s != null) {
    var len = s.length;
    input.value = s.join("/");
    if (len > 3) {
      var l = input.value.lastIndexOf('/');
      input.value = input.value.substring(0, l) + input.value.substring(l + 1);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="10">
```

Comment: That was awesome, man! Thank you so much! It Worked like a charm. Even though it accepts letters too, I am definetly going to use that!

Comment: @PedroHenrique Glad to help :) Would you like me to edit it to only accept numbers? I can do that